NTP client cannot sync date from a specific Server
I want to create a NTP server, and my clients could sync date from this Server.
So I add restrict policy in my server, and then restart the NTP service to my it works as a NTP server. Then I add this server to my clients, and remote other NTP servers and pools to make it the only NTP server in this client.
I have already run this command to check this server chosen by the client:
ntpq -pn

     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*xx.xx.xx.xx     91.189.91.157    3 u  342   64  340    0.087    8.349 4492269

As you can see, it works fine.  I also run ntpdate -q xx.xx.xx.xx to check the time by hand.
But I want to change a specific time in my NTP server, so I disabled all the pools in my NTP Server, and then using date -s to change the time. I also restarted this Server. The problem is that when I finished all these steps, the client cannot sync the datetime from my NTP server!
ntpdate -q xx.xx.xx.xx
server xx.xx.xx.xx, stratum 16, offset -26584.931234, delay 0.02574
27 Aug 07:23:49 ntpdate[1563239]: no server suitable for synchronization found

Does that mean I still need to define a pool or a server in my NTP server, and how could I change a specific time in my NTP server?

Your server is announcing stratum 16, which is the maximum stratum value. The stratum represents how many "tiers" of NTP servers is between ntpd and the reference clock, and having 16 intermediate steps would be... rather unusual and excessive. Such a long chain of NTP servers would be expected to accumulate so much delay/uncertainty that extending it any further would be pointless.
ntpd will also announce stratum 16 when it has not yet synchronized to any other NTP server or reference clock; in essence, it's saying "Don't trust me, I'm not yet really sure of the correct time with any serious accuracy".
To use ntpd the way you want, with no connection to any NTP server or reference clock, the modern way is to configure the orphan mode settings in your ntp.conf:
# If orphaned, serve others with this stratum.
tos orphan 8
# Wait for this many seconds before starting to serve others
tos orphanwait 300

With these settings, you would have to wait 5 minutes after starting your "master" ntpd before NTP clients can actually sync to it; if you have a mix of orphaned and non-orphaned (i.e. with a connection to a NTP server hierarchy with a reference clock on top), this allows the clients to pick a NTP server with higher-quality time than this one.
But in a situation where you are absolutely sure your NTP server will be the only one that's reachable, you should set the orphan stratum to 1 and minimize the orphanwait time:
tos orphan 1
tos orphanwait 10

NTP documentation reference here.
If you are using an old version of ntpd that does not support the orphan mode, the older way is to configure a fake timesource using the Undisciplined Local Clock reference clock driver:
# Undisciplined Local Clock. This is a fake driver intended for backup
# and when no outside source of synchronized time is available.
server  127.127.1.0     # local clock
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 8

This creates a fake reference clock that is always in 100% agreement with the kernel clock, so ntpd will trivially "sync" with it, and then will consider itself to be good enough for serving time information to others. The fudge command sets the stratum value of this fake reference clock to 8, so other NTP servers with a good connection to a nearby reference clock would still be preferred over it.
In your case, you would configure the Undisciplined Local Clock only in your "master" ntpd server, and only if it does not support the newer orphan mode.
No matter which type of configuration you use, setting the stratum to 8 or higher when using NTP to distribute some custom non-UTC timescale (like you're planning) is a good idea; it minimizes the risk of confusion if your custom NTP hierarchy ever accidentally ends up being reachable by clients from the outside world, that would generally expect a NTP server to provide NTP timestamps corresponding to the UTC timescale.
And like Stephen Harris said in another answer, if your machines are more than 1000 seconds apart and you want them synced quickly, you should stop any time-sensitive applications on the client, run ntpdate server.address to hard-jump the client to the correct second or so, then start ntpd to refine the synchronization from there.

The problem you're seeing is that the local client time and the remote server time are too far apart.  The maximum offset is 1000 seconds; your machines are 26,000 seconds apart!
The reason for this maximum limit is due to how ntpd works; it tries to adjust the local clock speed to allow it to come into sync.  With a large offset this could end up taking days or weeks, and during that time your clock is very wrong.
You can fix this on the client by stopping ntpd and running ntpdate server.address.  This will "hard jump" your client's time to match the server.  Now ntpd should restart cleanly.

It's a seven hour discrepancy (give or take). I suspect that the system clock has now been set to localtime instead of UTC
